# Construct and execute SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL script like so -

```
WHILE @year < year(getdate())

    BEGIN
        SET @table_name = 'Link_' + @year

        SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + @table_name + ' (a1, b1, REF, TYPE, Patients) 
   Select a1, b1, REF, TYPE, Count(Distinct a) Patients 
   From tb Where DATEPART(YEAR, THRU_DT) = ' + @year + ' 
   And REF Is Not Null And Active = 1 Group By a1, b1, REF, TYPE'

        SET @trunc = 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @table_name

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @trunc

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

        SET @YEAR = year(DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @YEAR))

        PRINT @year
    END
```

Is there a better way to construct sql statements and execute them? This gets the job done but it doesn't seem like a good practice.

Comment: Please be more specific. What part of it don't you like?

Comment: I'd question the design choice that results in a table for every year that creates the need for this particular kind of handling. As far as handling it better, I normally would have suggested prepare, but the variation on the table name is exactly what rules out bothering with that; you'd be doing a separate prepare every iteration.

Comment: If you *must* use dynamic SQL, **always** properly quote your dynamic objects. You could have a major injection here.

Comment: @Larnu That's exactly what I am concerned about. These are SQL scripts though. This code is not going to be run from a web application server. Does injection still matter in this case?

Comment: Injection, in my opinion, always matters. Just because you think it won't, doesn't mean it won't in the future if, say, requirements change. Properly quoting is always by far the safest option.

Comment: @Larnu I agree. What do you mean by properly quoting?

Comment: Why is your year variable defined as varchar? Choosing the wrong datatype flows into the rest of your logic. You should have statement terminators. And your insert query would be far more efficient by using the proper lower/upper boundaries rather than applying a function (datepart) to a column for similar logic.

Comment: I mean using things like `QUOTENAME`, @Aaron . A lot of people thinking that "properly" quoting a dynamic object would be to do `'[' + @TableName + ']'`, but just like any delimiter, the brackets (`[]`) can be escaped. That's why `QUOTENAME` should be used for objects, as it properly escapes the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a better understanding per the comments on your post, I believe this code sample is roughly what you're looking for. This does assume that @year is an integer (it should be), that @table_name is being provided somewhere - a cursor? and that the goal is to truncate the table prior to doing the insert, which appears to be the prior behavior.

```
WHILE @year < year(getdate())

    BEGIN
        SET @table_name = QUOTENAME('Link_' + @year);
        SET @sql = 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @table_name + '; INSERT INTO ' + @table_name + ' (a1, b1, REF, TYPE, Patients) 
   Select a1, b1, REF, TYPE, Count(Distinct a) Patients 
   From tb Where DATEPART(YEAR, THRU_DT) = @year 
   And REF Is Not Null And Active = 1 Group By a1, b1, REF, TYPE'

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@year int', @year = @year;

        SET @YEAR += 1; -- @year should be an integer, so that's how we handle it throughout

        RAISERROR('%d has been processed', 0, 1, @year) WITH NOWAIT;
    END
```

Comment: Does `QUOTENAME` protect against injection attacks?

Comment: Also, why do I need to pass `@year` as a variable when I already have it available in the while loop?

Comment: Hi Aaron. QUOTENAME is intended to help protect against attacks; however, it is not foolproof. I'd reference a resource like [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136273/should-we-still-be-using-quotename-to-protect-from-injection-attacks) to see more information about this part of it. You are passing @year as a variable because parameterized SQL is how you avoid SQL injection. Yes, you are *probably* safe from injection on this variable, but your request was for best practices, and thus I have used what is commonly considered a best practice for dynamic SQL. Does this help?

Comment: Part of the reason is because, let's say @year was typed in by the user when called a stored procedure -- in this scenario, I could declare year to be `'201; drop table users; GO;'` -- and this could cause an issue. *This example is oversimplified.* When you pass a variable to executeSQL, it's going to be parsed as pure text - it won't be able to escape itself. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/raulga/2007/01/04/dynamic-sql-sql-injection/)'s another example of a good explanation on parameterized SQL to avoid injection (Microsoft).